# Monitor Messages between application in C#

Tags: c#, dll, hook, code-injection

I would like to monitor windows messages that are generated during run-time. In order to achieve that I am trying to create a hook using:

```
hook = SetWindowsHookEx(HookId, delegatedfunction, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

When the `HookId` is either `WH_MOUSE_LL = 14` or `WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13`, everything works fine. The above function returns a `hook > 0` and I can monitor keystrokes and mouse events.  But when I choose any other `HookId` such as `WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4`, `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12`, `WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6`, etc, the above function returns `0` and nothing is monitored.

I have tried many different things and the only one that seems to properly creates the hook in these situations is when I am using a dll injection using the following code:

```
hook = SetWindowsHookEx(HookId, del, GetModuleHandle(fileName), 0);
```

The problem with this is that my app crashes after a while and I am not sure why this is happening since I have not used a dll injection in the past.

Can some please clarify any of the following:

> 1) Any idea why does it need a dll injection to create the hook on
>   those situations?
>
> 2) What kind of dll do I need when I am doing a dll
>   injection? Will any dll do or should I create one specifically for my
>   situation?

Comment: These hooks require an *unmanaged* DLL, you cannot inject C# code into another process.  The failure mode you describe is a standard problem with the delegate object you use.  The crash occurs when the object gets garbage collected.  Storing it in a static variable or using GCHandle.Alloc() is required to ensure that it can survive.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I need to get a dll (not compiled with .net) and load it in my app and then inject to that file? Also Can you please be a little more specific about what I need to do in order to fix the crash? Do I need to create a static variable for the hook and then do something lilke MyObject.hook = = SetWindowsHookEx(HookId, del, GetModuleHandle(fileName), 0);

Comment: Can some provide please some code as to how I can properly create the hook in order to monitor messages?